# While 3 of my states updating as expected in React onClick function, one of them falls behind

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a component that creates multiple-choice questions in react. When clicked to answers,
this component increase the number of correct or wrong answers been given, and calculates the overall correctness percentage. onClick function is :

```
const handleAnswer = (e) => {
        let correctItalianValue = correctAnswerContainer.current.innerText;
        if (e.target.innerText === correctEnglishValue(correctItalianValue)) {
            inCorrect()
        } else {
            inWrong()
        }
    }
```

if answer is correct I'm running below function if not another one:

```
    const inCorrect = () => {
        setCorrectAnswer(correctAnswer => correctAnswer + 1)
        setAnswerSum(answerSum => answerSum + 1)
        setAverageSuccess(val => percentage(answerSum, correctAnswer, wrongAnswer))
        setAnswer(answer => !answer)
    }

    const inWrong = () => {
        setWrongAnswer(wrongAnswer => wrongAnswer + 1)
        setAnswerSum(answerSum => answerSum + 1)
        setAverageSuccess(val => percentage(answerSum, correctAnswer, wrongAnswer))
        setAnswer(answer => !answer)
    }
    const percentage = (total, correct, wrong) => {
        if (correct === 0) {
            return 0
        } else if (wrong === 0) {
            return 100
        } else {
            return Math.round(100 * correct / total)
        }
    }
```

then, I'm passing these states as props to another component like this:

```
<AnswerCounter correctAnswer={correctAnswer} wrongAnswer={wrongAnswer}
                answerSum={answerSum} averageSuccess={averageSuccess} />
```

Inside that component, I' am rendering the number of correct and wrong questions together with total num of questions answered.

```
const AnswerCounter = ({ correctAnswer, wrongAnswer, answerSum, averageSuccess }) => {
    return (
        <section className="mt-5">
            <div className="d-flex justify-content-between mb-3">
                <h5>Correct: {correctAnswer}</h5>
                <h5>Wrong: {wrongAnswer}</h5>
                <h5>Total : {answerSum}</h5>
            </div>
            <div className="progress">
                <div className="progress-bar progress-bar-striped bg-dark" role="progressbar"
                    style={{ width: `${averageSuccess}%` }} aria-valuenow={averageSuccess}
                    aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">{averageSuccess} %
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
    )
}

export default AnswerCounter
```

While these data (correctAnswer, WrongAnswer, correctAnswer) correctly render, averageSuccess prop which helps me to show a progress bar, always fall behind one step or sometimes in start more than one. I know that updating state is async and needed to be dealt with passing previous state first and then update the state but that did not work as you can see. I also tried useEffect but did not work also. When I console.log averageSuccess when user answer a question by clicking one of the answer buttons, sometimes I see averageSuccess value as 0(initial value) even though two or three times button has been clicked and handleAnswer function called. I hope there is anyone who can help me. Thanks.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Comment: You have a stale closure. You're using a callback to set the average state, but still using the stale values. You'll need to increment them again for your average calculation, or move the average update into a `useEffect`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because I was using stale values to calculate average (in setAverageSuccess) as Brian said, moving it into useEffect hook solved my problem.